# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) - OpenGL Index Arrays

Tags: java, opengl, access-violation, jogl

### Problem

I am writing a JOGL program. After adding the `addModels()` method, it only runs for half a second, and then crashes, giving the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffa5567130d, pid=9684, tid=0x0000000000001c4c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig8icd64.dll+0xd130d]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Users\monke\workspace\TheGame1ByCaleb\hs_err_pid9684.mdmp
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\monke\workspace\TheGame1ByCaleb\hs_err_pid9684.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

### Code

Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
// appends model2 onto model1 and returns the new model
public static Model addModels (Model model1, Model model2) {
    Model model;

    int model1VertLen = model1.getVertices().length;
    int model2VertLen = model2.getVertices().length;

    int model1ColorLen = model1.getColors().length;
    int model2ColorLen = model2.getColors().length;

    int model1IndexLen = model1.getIndices().length;
    int model2IndexLen = model2.getIndices().length;

    float[] model1Vertices = model1.getVertices();
    float[] model2Vertices = model2.getVertices();

    float[] model1Colors = model1.getColors();
    float[] model2Colors = model2.getColors();

    int[] model1Indices = model1.getIndices();
    int[] model2Indices = model2.getIndices();

    float[] vertices = new float[model1VertLen + model2VertLen];
    float[] colors = new float[model1ColorLen + model2ColorLen];
    int[] indices = new int[model1IndexLen + model2IndexLen];

    // put all vertex data into one array
    System.arraycopy(model1Vertices, 0, vertices, 0, model1VertLen);
    System.arraycopy(model2Vertices, 0, vertices, model1VertLen, model2VertLen);

    // put all color data into one array
    System.arraycopy(model1Colors, 0, colors, 0, model1ColorLen);
    System.arraycopy(model2Colors, 0, colors, model1ColorLen, model2ColorLen);

    // "translate" (push up) index data by model1IndexLen in second model to match new array
    for (int i=0; i<model2Indices.length; i++) {
        model2Indices[i] += model1IndexLen;
    };

    // test
    for (int i=0; i<model2IndexLen; i++) {
        //indices[model1IndexLen+i] = 0;
    }

    // put all index data into one array
    System.arraycopy(model1Indices, 0, indices, 0, model1IndexLen);
    System.arraycopy(model2Indices, 0, indices, model1IndexLen, model2IndexLen);

    model = new Model(vertices, colors, indices);
    return model;
}
```

Also, here is a sample of a `Model`-returning method (`Model`s hold very large arrays containing vertex, color, and index data for OpenGL; this one's small, but they usually contains large arrays):

```
private static float[] getVertices (Matrix4 transf) {
        float[] vertices = {
                // bottom vertices
                -1,  0, -1,
                +1,  0, -1,
                 0,  0, +1,

                 0,  0,  0  // top (origin) 
        };
        for (int i=0; i<vertices.length; i+=3) {
            // get vertex data from vertices array
            float[] vertex = {vertices[i], vertices[i+1], vertices[i+2], 1};
            // transform vertex
            transf.multVec(vertex, vertex);
            // put vertex data into vertices array
            vertices[i] = vertex[0];
            vertices[i+1] = vertex[1];
            vertices[i+2] = vertex[2];
        }

        return vertices;
    }

    private static float[] getColors () {
        float[] colors = new float[3 * 3 * 4];  // 4 triangles, 3 vertices per tri, rgb for vertex
        for (int i=0; i<colors.length; i+=3) {
            colors[i+0] = 1;
            colors[i+1] = 1;
            colors[i+2] = 0;
        }

        return colors;
    }

    private static int[] getIndices () {
        return new int[] {
                // bottom
                0, 1, 2,

                // sides
                0, 1, 3,
                1, 2, 3,
                2, 0, 3
        };
    }

    public static Model getModel(Matrix4 transf) {
        return new Model(getVertices(transf), getColors(), getIndices());
    }

}
```

Lastly, here is the reference to this method in my main class:

```
Model terrainModel = Models.Terrain.getModel(terrain);
Model sunModel = Models.Sun.getModel(transformation);
Model model = Models.addModels(terrainModel, sunModel);
```

### More info

[hs_err_pid9684.log](https://pastebin.com/6MPPBQU5)

I tried exporting to JAR and running that in admin terminal, but that did not stop the crash.

### Conclusion

I hope the provided information was helpful, and I thank you in advance.

### EDIT

I changed

```
for (int i=0; i<model2Indices.length; i++) {
    model2Indices[i] += modelIndexLen;
};
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i<model2Indices.length; i++) {
    model2Indices[i] += model1VertLen;
};
```

and

```
    model2Indices[i] += model1VertLen / 3;  // divide by numb. of items per vertex
```

The problem was that I was pushing the second model's indices up by *the number of vertices* in the first model. That's incorrect. Add *the number of vertices (in the first model) divided by three* or four or how ever many items there are per vertex.
**And *that* got it to work!**

Comment: What is `Model`? Have you verified what `model1.getColors()` and `model2.getColors()` returns. How *much* do they return?

Comment: `Model` is a class I defined with the following fields: `float[] vertices`, `float[] colors`, and `int[] indices`. It has getters and a standard constructor. `model1.getColors()` and `model2.getColors()` both return as expected, with lengths `14616` and `36`, respectively.

Comment: First thing to do, open and look `C:\Users\monke\workspace\TheGame1ByCaleb\hs_err_pid9684.log`

Comment: Yes I did that, I'll post it in the question.

Comment: I have this same problem after copying my project into a new directory, some path that I'm using in OpenGL is no longer correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what I did. When I "pushed up" the indices for the second model (the code snippet in my edit), I pushed them up by the how many items were in the vertex array (`length` of the vertex array) of the first model, *not how many vertices it had*. **To calculate how many vertices there are, which is the correct number to push the indices up by, you must divide the length of the vertex array by three (or four).**

However, though this prevented the crash report, it still isn't concatenating the models correctly (it shows up glitchy on the screen).
If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, the help would be appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant lines in your log are always the first ones of the stacktrace

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.dispatch_glDrawElements1(IIILjava/lang/Object;IZJ)V+0
j  jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.glDrawElements(IIILjava/nio/Buffer;)V+99
j  run.TheGame1ByCaleb$ScenePlay.renderScene(Lcom/jogamp/opengl/GL2;)V+135
j  run.TheGame1ByCaleb$ScenePlay.display(Lcom/jogamp/opengl/GLAutoDrawable;)V+419
```

This means the crash happened in your `renderScene(GL2)`, when (one of) `glDrawElements` was called.

Usually these kind of crash have to do with buffers.

And since the relevant code for that is not shown, I can only suggest you to double check where you create and destroy your buffers and your vao (if you do use one).

One tricky bug to find, it's, for example, if you setup your vao, leave it bound and modify it accidentally by creating/uploading (later in the code) a new array/element buffer which will be change the status of the bound vao.

Comment: Maybe he simply forgot to reset the position within a direct NIO buffer. This kind of crash may occur when OpenGL tries to read beyond the end of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, but I did flip my buffers

Answer (score 1):

This is completely wrong:

> ```
> // "translate" (push up) index data by model1IndexLen in second model to match new array
> for (int i=0; i<model2Indices.length; i++) {
>     model2Indices[i] += model1IndexLen;
> };
> ```

The index array references vertices, not other indices. Wehn you copy two vertex arrays after each other, the indices of the second object will be offset by the number of *vertices* of the first object.

Comment: This makes sense. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that. I'll try it as soon as my IDE works.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) and mine was caused by the line `gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (long) Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT * 15 , buffer, GL.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);` where the "buffer" i passed in was size 12 instead of 15, creating a buffer overflow scenario that caused the OS to kill my process before anything useful was printed to java logs. Your problem doesn't look the EXACT same, but it looks very similar in the sense that you might have a buffer size miss-match. Hope this helps.